# How to calculate the Performance/timetaken of a HashSet Search

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, hashset

I have a HashSet of (a hashmap of (string and list of (hashmap of (two strings))))

```
HashSet<HashMap<String1,List<HashMap<String2,HashMap<String3,String4>>>>>
```

Now, I search with String inputs (StrA and StrB) and this should searches HashSet on

- StrA-->String1
- StrB-->String2

and it should return the hashMap of String 3 and String 4.

This is the code that I have

```
HashMap<String, String> mapFound;

for (HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>> map : fooSet) {
if (map.containsKey(string1)) {
    List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> list = map.get(string1);
    for(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map2 : list){
        if(map2.containsKey(string2)){
            mapFound = map2.get(string2);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have multiple sets of Hashmaps; some at the start of the set and some at the last. Some Hashmaps have few key value pairs and some have more.

Now, How do I measure the time taken for searching and result retrieval?

Comment: Does this work for what you need to do? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html

Comment: When you have a type signature like this `HashSet<HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>>>>` you know you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before loop:

```
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

After loop:

```
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

And of course it will give you every time a different result. Thats because your processor doing some other stuff at same time. But you can start it about 50-100 times and get the average value, to be more accurate.